# Detect Windows 10 theme changing in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to detect Windows 10 theme and I wrote this code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged;
    }

    private void SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged(object sender, UserPreferenceChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Category)
        {
            case UserPreferenceCategory.General:
                setTheme();
               break;
       }
   }

   private static bool ThemeIsLight()
   {
       RegistryKey registry =
           Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
               @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize");
       return (int)registry.GetValue("SystemUsesLightTheme") == 1;
   }

   public static void setTheme()
   { 
       var br = ThemeIsLight() ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Black;
       MessageBox.Show(br.ToString());
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Class1.setTheme();
}
```

The problem is that the code only works when the program is initially run, and the code does not run when the Windows theme is changed.
It works well if I write all the code in `MainWindow.cs`, but I want the code to be written in a separate class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code above does not create any instance of the `Class1`. Therefore, the `UserPreferenceChanged` event handler does not created.

It is necessary to create instance of `Class1`. For example:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Class1 DetectPreferenceChange = new Class1();
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }
    ...
}
```

**Or, if it is necessary to subscribe to the event without creating of the `Class1` instance do the following:**

Change signature of the event handler to `public static`:

```
public static void SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged(object sender, UserPreferenceChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    // ...
}
```

And now you can subscribe to the event directly:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged += (s, e) => { Class1.SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged(s, e); };
}
```

Because of all methods in the class are `static` now the class constructor might be omitted and class can be declared as `static`.

For additional information see [How to subscribe to and unsubscribe from events (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)

Comment: is there any way to do this without creating instance of Class1?

Comment: @hadi khodabandeh: Good question! Answer: **Yes.** I will update my answer.